# Multistep form loses input when visiting previous step

Tags: 7, forms

I am developing a custom module with the ability to store data on an external database using Drupal 7 Form API.
I started with the multistep form example, added few more steps and other fields.

To implement the ability to edit those data I created a class that retrieves returns an array suitable to fill the $form_state['values'] element in order to have a default value for each form element. Here follows the code I have in the form callback when going to edit my data:

```
if( !empty($form_state['build_info']['args'][0]) ) ) {
    $a = new ind();
    $a->get_ind( $form_state['build_info']['args'][0] );

    $form_state['values'] = get_object_vars($a);
    unset($a);
}
```

Problem is when I hit the previous/next buttons because of the form is being rebuilt always with the data from the class so every change in a field is lost when hitting "Previous"; suddenly every change gets lost when I click "Next" after "Previous" (fields are empty!).

How do you achieve editing with multistep form with existing data? I am stuck here attempting to put the code above at submit and previous handlers with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `if` statement with `#triggering_element` or `#clicked_button`. Example:

```
function PREVIOUS_STEP_submission_OR_SOME_KIND_OF_CALLBACK($form, &$form_state) {
  if($form_state['clicked_button']['#value'] == 'BACK') {
    //show_previous_step()
  }
  else {
    $a = new ind();
    $a->get_ind( $form_state['build_info']['args'][0] );

    $form_state['values'] = get_object_vars($a);
    unset($a);
    // or your logic
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this logic but I should fill default values only once (ie. the first time I open the form in edit mode), or I would loose any change. So, the workflow is: 1) open the form with the values fetched from the database 2) fill and/or edit the form with those default.

Comment: @user18993 ok, let's imagine, I open the empty(new) form and start to fill the fields and I can continue to next step or go back to previous steps, right? in this case `#clicked_button` works fine, it restores values from somekind of temporary storage. But when I finish the form, I want to change something and I open it and try to move by steps, here problems begin, right?

Comment: ok, step2: the form is filled with my defaults step3: form is filled with default but i go back to step2 and... previously made changes are lost, moreover if I go again to step3, fields are blank. That's the situation.

Comment: @user18993 how did you create your multistep form? Here is a another way to create MS form: http://davidsonj.com/blog/how-create-multi-step-form-drupal-7

Comment: I started with the drupal7 form example module, form_example_wizard.inc file, then added other steps and validation functions.

Comment: here is the really code I use from line #1 to line #190. I guess I should add an element in the $form_state array, such a boolean flag to retrieve data from the class only once for each step. http://drupalcode.org/project/examples.git/blob/HEAD:/form_example/form_example_wizard.inc